# ESLint does not get types of child projects in monorepo

Tags: typescript, eslint, monorepo, typescript-eslint

I have a Typescript monorepo setup with yarn workspaces and I use tsconfig->paths for development.

When I run `eslint`, types from other packages in the same monorepo seem to have type `any` and the linter throws false positives as a result.

Type of false positives:

- `Invalid type "any" of template literal expression @typescript-eslint/restrict-template-expressions`
- `This assertion is unnecessary since it does not change the type of the expression @typescript-eslint/no-unnecessary-type-assertion`
- `Operands of '+' operation must either be both strings or both numbers @typescript-eslint/restrict-plus-operands`

I would like to add that fixing any of those issues will result in build errors thrown by `tsc`.

Any thoughts how this could be avoided?

Comment: I had something similar - was seeing what looked like a false positive on `@typescript-eslint/restrict-plus-operands`.  In my case though I only saw it when running in GitHub actions - and the reason why was because I'm using yarn workspaces, and needed to run "build" before I ran "lint" so that the workspace to workspace `.d.ts` files were produced.